# Python: variable scope and encapsulation of a list

Tags: python

I have a class Map (simplified):

```
from Enums import *
import Globals
import Tile

class Map:
    tiles = []  #the actual map, it's a 2D list of Tile objects
    for x in range(Globals.mapWidth):
        for y in range(Globals.mapHeight):
            self.tiles[x][y].addItem(Items.Foliage)
```

And a class Tile:

```
class Tile:
    items=[]
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type

    def addItem(self,i):
        self.items.append(i)
```

My problem is that the items[] array from the class Tile seems to be shared within every instanciation of the class. For example, at the end of the FOR loops, 
    print(len(self.tiles[x][y].items)
return 25 for every tile. Why is it so? I should have 25 lists of size 1, but instead printing the list size in the loop increases from 0 to 25. Can someone explan to me what happens here? Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `items` is a class attribute, which is why it appears to be shared between all the instances.

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.items = []
        self.type = type
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'll accept your answer when the website allows me

Comment: Say while you're here, how can I test if list.index() returns an error? I can't find this on Google.

Comment: @gramm, use a try/except http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @gramm: `try: my_list.index(x); except ValueError: handle_error()`